# How do I change db schema to dbo

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, schema

I imported a bunch of tables from an old sql server (2000) to my 2008 database.  All the imported tables are prefixed with my username, for example: `jonathan.MovieData`.  In the table `properties` it lists `jonathan` as the db schema.  When I write stored procedures I now have to include `jonathan.` in front of all the table names which is confusing.

How do I change all my tables to be dbo instead of jonathan?

Current result: `jonathan.MovieData`

Desired result: `dbo.MovieData`

Answer (score 195, accepted):

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER jonathan.MovieData;
```

See [ALTER SCHEMA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173423.aspx).

**Generalized Syntax:**

```
ALTER SCHEMA TargetSchema TRANSFER SourceSchema.TableName;
```

Comment: To save time for Googlers: ALTER SCHEMA TargetSchema TRANSFER SourceSchema.TableName;

Comment: If the user has a backslash run the following: ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER "DOMAIN\user".tableName

Comment: @PatricF The [quoted identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx) rules apply to schema names just as to any other name: `[DOMAIN\user].[tableName]`.  In general in SQL Server community the Transact-SQL quoted identifiers are used (`[` and `]`), avoid `"` unless there is a a specific requirement for it.

Comment: As He asked for **all my Tables** , check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1149168/2218697) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10943302/2218697) to do it in single statement, hope helps some one.

Comment: @Co7e:i have updated the answer as per your comment,Thanks

Comment: What if the domain is included? SQL doesn't like the backslash. `... TRANSFER domain\user123.TableName` seems to be invalid syntax and yet that's the schema.

Comment: @leigero use `[` and `]`, like any other case when you want to be precise about a SQL object name. `[domain\user123].TableName`.

Answer (score 44):

You can run the following, which will generate a set of ALTER sCHEMA statements for all your talbes:

```
SELECT 'ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'jonathan'
```

You then have to copy and run the statements in query analyzer.

Here's an older script that will do that for you, too, I think by changing the object owner. Haven't tried it on 2008, though.

```
DECLARE @old sysname, @new sysname, @sql varchar(1000)

SELECT
  @old = 'jonathan'
  , @new = 'dbo'
  , @sql = '
  IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE
      QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA)+''.''+QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) = ''?''
      AND TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' + @old + '''
  )
  EXECUTE sp_changeobjectowner ''?'', ''' + @new + ''''

EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable @sql
```

Got it from [this site](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2004/01/30/SQL-Table-Ownership-Changes_2C00_-Quick-and-Easy.aspx).

It also talks about doing the same for stored procs if you need to.

Comment: I tried the second bit to no avail, but thanks for the link, I'll look into it.

Comment: Were you not able to use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA select above to generate all your ALTER SCHEMA statements automatically?

Comment: Note the following quote from the [documentation of INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/tables-transact-sql): *"**Important** Do not use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views to determine the schema of an object. The only reliable way to find the schema of an object is to query the sys.objects catalog view."* Thus, the example should be rewritten to use `sys.tables` (a subset of sys.objects) instead.

Comment: I would suggest manually alter the tables to dbo rather than some loop, just to be sure. This is a very crucial operation.
https://www.sqlfreelancer.com/blog/?p=381

Answer (score 22):

```
USE MyDB;
GO
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER jonathan.MovieData;
GO
```

Ref: [ALTER SCHEMA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173423.aspx)

Answer (score 17):

**Move table from dbo schema to MySchema:**

```
 ALTER SCHEMA MySchema TRANSFER dbo.MyTable
```

**Move table from MySchema to dbo schema:**

```
 ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER MySchema.MyTable
```

Answer (score 10):

I just posted this to a similar question: [In sql server 2005, how do I change the "schema" of a table without losing any data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89606/in-sql-server-2005-how-do-i-change-the-schema-of-a-table-without-losing-any-d/10502805#10502805)

---

A **slight** improvement to sAeid's excellent answer...

I added an exec to have this code self-execute, and I added a union at the top so that I could change the schema of both tables AND stored procedures:

```
DECLARE cursore CURSOR FOR 


select specific_schema as 'schema', specific_name AS 'name'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.routines
WHERE specific_schema <> 'dbo' 

UNION ALL

SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA AS 'schema', TABLE_NAME AS 'name'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA <> 'dbo' 



DECLARE @schema sysname, 
 @tab sysname, 
 @sql varchar(500) 


OPEN cursore     
FETCH NEXT FROM cursore INTO @schema, @tab 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0     
BEGIN 
 SET @sql = 'ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER [' + @schema + '].[' + @tab +']'    
 PRINT @sql   
 exec (@sql)  
 FETCH NEXT FROM cursore INTO @schema, @tab     
END 

CLOSE cursore     
DEALLOCATE cursore
```

I too had to restore a dbdump, and found that the schema wasn't dbo - I spent hours trying to get Sql Server management studio or visual studio data transfers to alter the destination schema...  I ended up just running this against the restored dump on the new server to get things the way I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

You can batch change schemas of multiple database objects as described in this post:

[How to change schema of all tables, views and stored procedures in MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571233/how-to-transfer-all-tables-views-and-stored-procedures-from-one-schema-to-anoth/17571234#17571234)

Answer (score 2):

Way to do it for an individual thing:

alter schema dbo transfer jonathan.MovieData

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue but my schema had a backslash in it. In this case, include the brackets around the schema.

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER [DOMAIN\jonathan].MovieData;
```

Answer (score 2):

Open SQL Server as SA account and click on new query past the below queries

then click on execute, it will rollback all owned schema back to SA account

```
alter authorization on schema::[db_datareader] to [dbo]
alter authorization on schema::[db_datareader] to [db_datareader]
alter authorization on schema::[db_datawriter] to [dbo]
alter authorization on schema::[db_datawriter] to [db_datawriter]
alter authorization on schema::[db_securityadmin] to [dbo]
alter authorization on schema::[db_securityadmin] to [db_securityadmin]
alter authorization on schema::[db_accessadmin] to [dbo]
alter authorization on schema::[db_accessadmin] to [db_accessadmin]
alter authorization on schema::[db_backupoperator] to [dbo]
alter authorization on schema::[db_backupoperator] to [db_backupoperator]
alter authorization on schema::[db_ddladmin] to [dbo]
alter authorization on schema::[db_ddladmin] to [db_ddladmin]
alter authorization on schema::[db_owner] to [dbo]
alter authorization on schema::[db_owner] to [db_owner]
```

Answer (score 1):

ms-help://MS.SQLCC.v9/MS.SQLSVR.v9.en/tsqlref9/html/0a760138-460e-410a-a3c1-d60af03bf2ed.htm

ALTER SCHEMA schema_name TRANSFER securable_name

Answer (score 0):

Use this code if you want to change all tables, views, and procedures at once.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(MAX)
        , @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
        , @oldSchema NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'MyOldSchema'
        , @newSchema NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'dbo'
        
DECLARE objCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT  o.name
        FROM    sys.objects o
        WHERE   type IN ('P', 'U', 'V')

OPEN    objCursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM objCursor INTO @name
        WHILE   @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = 'ALTER SCHEMA '+ @newSchema +' TRANSFER '+ @oldSchema + '.' +  @name         
            BEGIN TRY
                exec(@sql)
                PRINT 'Success: ' + @sql
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                PRINT 'Error executing: ' + @sql
            END CATCH
            FETCH NEXT FROM objCursor INTO @name
        END
CLOSE   objCursor
DEALLOCATE  objCursor
```

END

It will execute a code like this

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER MyOldSchema.xx_GetUserInformation
```