# System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing th

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a connectionstring in mvc3 application and it is working fine in mvc views and controllers and I am able to fetch data. Now I have called the repository/model functions in a Unit Test in Test project and I am getting error:

```
System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.tblProduct'.
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That has nothing to do particularly with MVC. As it seems, when testing, you use ConnectionString on database that does not have 'dbo.tblProduct' table/view. Check the connetion string and database. You may need to debug tests

Answer (score 2):

Check your table may have different schema (other then dbo) change it to dbo using query below

look at this.
[How do I change db schema to dbo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146599/sql-2008-how-do-i-change-db-schema-to-dbo)

Answer (score 0):

Its very strange for my case, as it is required to do mapping between model and tables, the name has to be the same. When I added 's' at the end of table's name, it works. I don't know if this part work of what LINQ does.