# How do you change the database schema to dbo

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How do I change tables and views to be dbo instead of `DOMAIN\username`?

Currently: `DOMAIN\username.Data`

Preferred: `dbo.Data`

Comment: see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146599/how-do-i-change-db-schema-to-dbo

Comment: I tried the link you suggested but it doesn't work, or I couldn't get it to work for DOMAIN\username.  SQL give an error of incorrect syntax near '\'.

Comment: sorry the link is not working for you.  It is from stack overflow, just search to "how do i change db schema to dbo" and it will be the top hit

Comment: @Puzzled .. The Stackoveflow is correct but if you have `Domain\username` you need to encase with `[` and `]` .. `ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER [Domain\username].MovieData;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER [DOMAIN\username].Data;
```